# Apple-seed-sized black bug, not very leggy - (Canada)

Tags: species-identification, entomology, pest-control

Can anyone identify this bug:

[image]

I'm in Toronto (Canada), 9th floor of a highrise building.  Most of the apartment is wall-to-wall carpeting, though the kitchen, entrance, and washroom are tiled.

Comment: We're going to need a better picture.

Comment: Darn.  I killed it and flushed it.  :(

Comment: Can you describe it? How does it move? Where's the head in this picture? Maybe even label the picture you have.

Comment: Sorry, I can't.  I'm at the age where progessive lenses are needed.  I was actually relying on the photograph to be able to see the details better.  At least it doesn't look like a bed bug, but I am curious what it is.